# Query data from mysql database using where statement and use in Django template

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a DB table with data like :

```
ID    epic_key     issue_key     status
1     JIR-1         JIR-12        TODO
2     JIR-2         JIR-13        OPEN
3     JIR-2         JIR-18        CLOSE
4     JIR-2         JIR-88        TODO
5     JIR-3         JIR-89        TODO
6     JIR-3         JIR-99        CLOSE
```

My Views.py looks like

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Jirareport.objects.values('epic_key').distinct()
    latest_issue_list = Jirareport.objects.all()
    context2 = {'latest_issue_list': latest_issue_list}
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context,context2)
```

And the piece of code in index.HTML is

> `% for question in latest_issue_list %}   <div data-role="main"
>   class="ui-content">
>       <div data-role="collapsible">
>         <h1>{{question.epic_key}}</h1>
>
>         <p>{{question.issue_key}}</p>
>       </div>    </div> {% endfor %}`

Question : My ask is to display unique values of column "**epic_key**" and all values of column "**issue_key**" in

statement provided in the html.

Just like this

For the epic_key =

```
**JIR - 2** 
JIR-13
JIR-18
JIR-88
```